How can I disable suggestions with the "~" (tilde) in LazyVim?
When I type something inside the TypeScript object, LazyVim suggests additional hints in the suggestions window. How can I disable them?
Current suggestions:
getUser_repo
getUser_repo~
createBeautyPage_repo
createBeautyPage_repo~

Expected suggestions:
getUser_repo
createBeautyPage_repo



In LazyVim, I replaced the tilde by a dragon head emoji (but you can just make it blank), because somehow wavy ends make me feel itchy...
return {
  {
    "hrsh7th/nvim-cmp",
    opts = {
      formatting = {
        format = function(_, vim_item)
          vim_item.abbr = vim_item.abbr:gsub("~$", "")
          return vim_item
        end,
      },
    },
  },
}

Just add this in a file in plugins/ in your LazyVim config and you're good to go.
Example setup:


